# Detect UIWebview's FPS

Tags: ios, uiwebview, frame-rate

I am building an iOS App,use UIWebview to load any pages.How can I detect every page's FPS?Or the FPS of the App?I want to show the FPS meter to user who use my App to view his pages.
I know there is no such API for me to do it.Can I use CADisplayLink to draw something then calculate the PFS?How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know there is no such API for me to do it.

Because a ViewController it is displayed as needed. 
If you don't have any actions, than the same will be displayed, so FPS = 0.000000001 on that case

Comment: Does webpage rendering not belong to ACTION?